# Purpose of --wait=false in minikube start command

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to kubernetes.

Can someone please explain that what is the real purpose of **"--wait=false"** in `minikube start --wait=false` command?

I am not able to find the appropriate answer in internet.

Answer (score 1):

[minikube start -options](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/#options)

According to documentation:

```
--wait strings                      comma separated list of Kubernetes components to verify and wait for after starting a cluster. defaults to "apiserver,system_pods", available options: "apiserver,system_pods,default_sa,apps_running,node_ready,kubelet" . other acceptable values are 'all' or 'none', 'true' and 'false' (default [apiserver,system_pods])
```